# Calling internal api on button click in Shopify app

Tags: reactjs, shopify

I want to call an internal API call on button click, but the code I have also do the call on page load.

This is the code:

```
import { useNavigate, TitleBar, Loading } from "@shopify/app-bridge-react";
import {
  Card,
  EmptyState,
  Layout,
  Page,
  SkeletonBodyText,
} from "@shopify/polaris";
import { QRCodeIndex } from "../components";
import { SynchButton } from '../components/SnychButton';
import { useAppQuery } from "../hooks";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

export default function HomePage() {

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  // emulates a fetch (useQuery expects a Promise)
  const emulateFetch = _ => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      resolve([{ data: "ok" }]);
    });
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    refetch();
  };


  const { data, refetch } = useAppQuery({
    url: "/api/products",
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    enabled: false // disable this query from automatically running
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // Prevent initial fetch
    // Do nothing or perform any necessary operations here
  }, []);

  return (

    <Page>
      
      <TitleBar
        title="SYNCH"
        primaryAction={{
          content: "Synch",
          onAction: handleClick,
        }}
        
      />

      <Layout>
        <Layout.Section>

        </Layout.Section>
      </Layout>
    </Page>
  );
}
```

I tried to place the api call into a separate function, but the call cannot be called like that. I need the API cal only on button click.

Edit
I found the solution:

```
const handleSubmit = React.useCallback((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    useFetch("/api/products");
  }, []);
  

  return (
    <Page>
      
      <form>
        {/* fields and everything */}
        <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
      </form>
      
      <Layout>
        <Layout.Section>

        </Layout.Section>
      </Layout>
    </Page>
  );
```

Original link: https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apps/call-authenticated-custom-api-endpoint-in-app-from-client-side/td-p/1558157